# Mysql query to select row based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

| id | date | is_available | product_id | product_recalled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 2019-10-10 | 1 | 123 | yes |
| 201 | 2020-07-10 | 1 | 123 | no |
| 202 | 2020-08-11 | 0 | 123 | yes |
| 203 | 2021-07-10 | 0 | 123 | yes |
| 204 | 2021-01-10 | 0 | 123 | no |
| 205 | 2021-07-10 | 0 | 124 | yes |
| 206 | 2021-01-10 | 0 | 124 | no |

I need a query to select the max row based on the is_available column value sorted by latest date. If is_available = 1 for the product, I should get the max row for with is_available = 0. Similarly, if a product only has is_available set to 0, I should get the max row for is_available = 0.

If a product id has both is_available =1 and is_available = 0, then I need to get the latest record with is_available = 1 which is the case for product id 123. For product id 124, there is no is_available = 1 so I need to get the latest record with is_available = 0.

Eg: Scenario 1: If I specify the product_id = 123, then the expected output should be

| id | date | is_available | product_id | product_recalled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 2020-07-10 | 1 | 123 | no |

Scenario 2: If I specify the product_id = 124, then the expected output should be

| id | date | is_available | product_id | product_recalled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 205 | 2021-07-10 | 0 | 124 | yes |

I am not sure how to write a single query that would do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say you want the latest row where `is_available = 0` for both cases, yet in your expected table, you show `is_available = 1` for product_id 123. I also don't understand where `is_available` is coming from. How do you determine whether or not a product is available?

Comment: @xyldke If a product id has both is_available =1 and is_available = 0, then I need to get the latest record with is_available =1 eg: for product id 123. For product id 124, there is no is_available = 1 so I need to get the latest record with is_available = 0.

Comment: @Akina can you help me with the full query? I tried with the partition but it is not working in mysql.

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY is_available DESC, date DESC) rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

For to select the row for definite product use

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE product_id = @product_id
ORDER BY is_available DESC, date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bhgIcnnW)

Comment: Thank you. I have never used partition much before. Do I need to write this as a pl/sql?

Comment: @user3376592 ??? MySQL does not support PL/SQL.

Comment: I meant to ask if I should write this as a stored procedure?

Comment: @user3376592 No, this is single query. And fiddle demonstrates this...